# Paginating results view with previous, next buttons in JSP

Tags: java, mysql, model-view-controller, jsp, pagination

I have certain analysis results displayed on a page. But currently all of the results are displayed and there are more than 300 results on the page. I want to paginate the results with the analyses results of the most recent 10 submissions with the ability to navigate to older results with page number hyperlinks at the bottom of the results. I am using the MVC framework. The javascript for displaying the analyses results functionality in a JSP. I am using mySQL as the database. How would I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the open-source [Display tag library](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/). It provides the ability to implement pagination, internal or external sorting, decorators, and much more via the [display:table attributes](http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/displaytag/tagreference.html#display%3atable). It also eliminates the need for a lot of custom scriptlet code inside your JSPs.

Without getting too deep into your specific use case, here is a start to how you might apply the library to your needs:

```
<display:table name="analysisList" defaultsort="1" pagesize="10" sort="list" uid="element">
  <display:column title="ID"                sortable="true"  property="id" />
  <display:column title="Date Submitted"    sortable="true"  property="date_created" />
  <display:column title="Notes"             sortable="true">
    <c:out value="${fn:replace(element.notes, "**-3**", "")}" />
  </display:column>
  <display:column title="Status"            sortable="true">
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${element.id eq -1}">
            ...
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${element.xml_path eq null and fn:contains(element.notes, "-3")}">
            ...
        </c:when>
        <c:when test="${element.xml_path eq null}">
            ...
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
            Report attached
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
  <display:column title="Similarity Search" sortable="true">
    ... similar idea as above ...
  </display:column>
</display:table>
```

Comment: Thanks Beau. Can you also suggest how I would use display tag in the JSP I had provided? Because the examples in the website are way different from what I am doing!

Comment: I've updated the example to be a starting place for you to extend the library to your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this C:/pagination.js file ..simple pagination

This is a simple example of pagination using java script

You can link the pagination.js file to your web page .

See below code of pagination.js and a sample html file

```
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) {
    this.tableName = tableName;
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pages = 0;
    this.inited = false;   
    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {       
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i < from || i > to) 
                rows[i].style.display = 'none';
            else
                rows[i].style.display = '';
        }
    }   
    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) {
         if (! this.inited) {alert("not inited");
         return;
         }
         if(pageNumber=="last")
         pageNumber=this.pages;      
         if(pageNumber=="first")
         pageNumber="1";         
        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';       
        this.currentPage = pageNumber;
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage);
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected';
        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1;
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1;
        this.showRecords(from, to);
    }  
    this.incrFont = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
         alert("not inited");
         return;
        }
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+pageNumber);       
        var res=newPageAnchor.className=="pg-normal";       
        if(res)
           newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-focused';           
       }       
    this.decrFont = function(pageNumber) {
        if (! this.inited) {
         alert("not inited");
         return;
        }
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+pageNumber);
        if(newPageAnchor.className!="pg-selected")
           newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal';        
       }     
    this.prev = function() {
        if (this.currentPage > 1)
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1);
    }   
    this.next = function() {
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) {
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1);
        }
    } 
    this.init = function() {
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows;
        var records = (rows.length - 1);
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage);
        this.inited = true;
        this.addStyle();
    }
    //showPageNav = function(pagerName, div_id, default pageNumber)
    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId, pageNumber) {
        this.init();
     if (! this.inited) {
      alert("not inited");
      return;
     }
     var element = document.getElementById(positionId);
     var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> &#171 Prev </span> | ';
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');" onmouseover="' + pagerName + '.incrFont(' + page + ');" onmouseout="' + pagerName + '.decrFont(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | ';
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next &#187;</span>';
        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml;
        this.showPage(pageNumber);
    }   
}
```

index.html file

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Paging Table example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:/pagination.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">   
            .pg-normal {
                color: blue;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: none;cursor: pointer;font-size: 12pt;  
            }
            .pg-selected {
                color: green;font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;font-size: 12pt; 
            }
            .pg-focused {
                color: red;font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;font-size: 12pt;
            }
        </style>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var pager;
    function formatTable()
    {
           //new Pager("table_page","number of rows in per page")
           pager = new Pager("tbl_AddGrid", 3);
           //showPageNav("pager object","div id for page links","default page no");        
           pager.showPageNav("pager","div_TableMIS",1);        
    }
    //--></script> 
</head>
<body>
<table id="table_page">
            <tr><th>Sl No</th><th>field</th></tr>
            <tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec1"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec2"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>3</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec3"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>4</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec4"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>5</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec5"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>6</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec6"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>7</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec7"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>8</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec8"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>9</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec9"></td></tr>
            <tr><td>10</td><td><input type="text" name="field-name" value="rec10"></td></tr>
        </table>
<div id="pageNavPosition" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```